# Fair coin flip problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Given a fair coin which is flipped $n$ times in succession, and let $X_t$ be the number of heads received among the first $t$ flips. Let $m < n$. I need to calculate the probability 
>   that there exists a $t \in [m, n]$ such that $X_t > \frac{3t}{4}$.

Since the fair coin flipping is a binomial problem, let $P(X_t)$ = ${t}\choose{X_t - t}$$(\frac{1}{2})^{X_t}$. Thus, I can let $P(X_t) \geq \frac{3t}{4}$. Is my process correct?

Comment: I don't think you've said anything *wrong*, but I'm not sure how it would be possible to complete that to an answer to the original question. Note that the original question requires consideration of several values of $t$ simultaneously (specifically, $t \in \{m, m+1, \dots, n\}$), and that for $t, s$ in that range, $X_t$ and $X_s$ are certainly not independent of one another. It seems to me that you'll need some rather different idea to solve the problem, but maybe I'm just lacking creativity at the moment.

Comment: The expression $P(X_t) = \binom t{X_t-t}\left(\frac12\right)^{X_t}$ does not make any sense. What is the probability of a random variable?